# 3706: Syntax error: expected something between 'field_name ' and the 'AS' keyword

Tags: teradata-sql-assistant

> 3706: Syntax error: expected something between 'field_name ' and the 'AS' keyword

I am getting above error with the script below in teradata for same query that works in SSMS.

```
SELECT  T.PO_NBR, T.PO_DATE, T.PO_LINE_NBR, T.RDC_NBR, T.UPDATE_USERID, UPC_NUM, MODEL_NUM, ITEM_DESCRIPTION, WEEK_NBR
FROM MF_PRD_VIEWS.PLAT_PO_LN_ALLOC T 
JOIN MF_PRD_VIEWS.POLT_PO_LINE O ON T.PO_NBR = O.PO_NBR AND T.PO_DATE = O.PO_DATE AND T.RDC_NBR = O.RDC_NBR
JOIN MF_PRD_VIEWS.FSYT_FISCAL_YEAR Y ON T.PO_DATE = Y.DATE_IN_YEAR
AS P1
-WHERE T.PO_date >= '2021-01-01' AND ((SELECT COUNT(UPC_NUM) AS EXPR1

FROM   MF_PRD_VIEWS.POLT_PO_LINE AS P2

WHERE   (P1.RDC_NUM = P2.RDC_NUM AND P1.WEEK_NBR = P2.WEEK_NUM AND P1.UPC_NUM = P2.UPC_NUM)) > 1)
```

Comment: Not sure exactly what is missing, but something seems to be. You have `AS P1` that does not seem to apply to any object, though you have references to P1 in the subquery.

Comment: P1 is supposed to be the alias for the data selected with the prior query. This works just fine in SSMS and I have used variations of the query over the years in that environment. I am new to Teradata.

Comment: Perhaps if you supply some sample data and expected output it would allow someone to offer an answer. This exact query cannot be working in SSMS.

Comment: I used a variation of this over the years. I just expanded it. I have also realized that I don't need the need 3 joins as the second join has the same fields and more than the original table so I just need the second table.--SELECT     Sku, Grade, Part_Num, Description
--FROM         DimProducts AS p1
--WHERE     ((SELECT     COUNT(Part_Num) AS Expr1
  --                       FROM         DimProducts AS p2
    --                     WHERE     (p1.Part_Num = Part_Num)) > 1)

Comment: Those are not even the same tables & columns as what you posted above. I'd suggest you delete this question and if you still have an issue (or have a different issue) then post a new question with a bit more detail.